# Importing EXR's Image Squence into Blender

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, file-format

How do I import an EXR image sequence? (assuming I'm doing it wrong). ie.Compositing tab-> Input> Image Sequence> Open etc?

My .exrs are not displaying. I also tried in the Video Editing tab-> Add>Image Sequence & nothing displays. Trying to re-import my rendered OpenEXR. Float (Full).

[image]

FIXED: I used Renamer to add-in .exr to the end of all the files & it does import in fine.
[image]

Comment: Where are they not displaying?

Comment: In blender, when you click on the add image sequence node a window opens. Can you select the files there?